# I am trying to make a custom User creation with ZenDesk(CRM)

Tags: php, httprequest, zendesk-app

This site helped me out a lot last time I had an issue.  I was wondering why this php code was not working.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am trying to make a custom user creation request with ZenDesk.

I got the request to work, but when I edited the code to fit it into the actual Instance of my CRM it does not even try to make a PHP request.  I verified this should be possible if the code is correct.  I Just can not figure out why it is not correct.

```
<?php

include("config.php");




$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url/api/v2/users.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"user\": {\"name\": \"$name\", 
\"email\": \"$email\", \"phone\": \"$phone"}}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "email" . ":" . "password");

$phone = phone;
$email = email;
$name = name;
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

if ( !isset ($_POST['Name']) ||
    !isset ($_POST['Name'] ||
    !isset ($_POST['phone']
            )
            {

            }
curl_close ($ch);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form 
action="://url/agent/users/{{user.id}}/requested_tickets">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="name">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="email">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="+15555555555">
 <br><br>    
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a 
page 
called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```